# Angular HTTP POST request to spring boot resulting in null value

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, post

I was having some problem when trying to execute POST request with multiple parameters. Here is my service.ts class written in typescript:

```
   retrieve(packageId: any[], date: any) {
    console.log(packageId);
    console.log(date);
    let packgeIdStr: string = JSON.stringify(packageId);
    const data = { stringArrDo: packgeIdStr, date: date };
    const url = this.serviceAPI + '/...../retrieve';
    return this.http.post<SRFDO[]>(
        url,
        { params: data }
    );
}
```

When I print out in my console, I managed to get the data here.

[image]

However, when I pass the data to my controller written in Java, the parameters became null:

```
@PostMapping("/retrieve")
public DO[] retrieve(@RequestBody String stringArrDo, java.sql.Date date)
        throws RemoteException, JaMClientRemoteException, JaMException {
            System.out.println(stringArrDo);
            System.out.println("date :"+ date);
    // removed code
}
```

[image]

I not sure why the data is printed out at service.ts but when passing it to the controller then became null. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open up your Chrome dev tools, go to the Network tab, and inspect your POST to see if angular is actually passing the right stuff to the right endpoint. That will tell you if your problem is client-side vs server-side.

Edit:
It looks like your server may be expecting an array of strings, but you're sending an object. In javascript, when you do `{var1, var2}`, that's just shorthand for `{var1: var1Value, var2: var2Value}`

Edit 2: I looked up spring, and it looks like you're using `@RequestBody` incorrectly. It looks like you're supposed to pass it a class that it can deserialize the JSON into, like

```
public class RequestData {
    private String[] packageIds;
    private Date date;
    // ...
}
```

You've also put your data under the top-level variable `params`, so you'd want to remove that and put all your stuff at the top level of your object.

Try reading through this tutorial for more info: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Comment: It says 500 internals server error. And I checked the request payload the parameters are actually populated with the values I printed out in my console.

Comment: I was thinking could it be the reason of different parameters type at the controller which was causing this issue?

Comment: So it sounds like the issue is serverside since you're getting a 500. Your server should be telling you what the actual error is so you can fix it, either in the 500 response, or in your logs.

Comment: Also, you may be expecting the wrong datatype. See my edit.

Comment: Hey I have updated my question. Do you mind to take a look?

Comment: Updated, I looked up spring, looks like you're using its deserialization incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes name on two classes may be different.

```
class A{ 
     // class in springboot
     private String name;
   }



 class A { 
//class in angular 
data: String; 
}
```

In this case, attribute name is main cause for null pointer exception in server side.